# How to search for all elements matching a "dynamic" name

Tags: jquery

```
        $(".gl").hover(function() {
    $('select[name="' + $(this).attr('name') + '"]').removeClass("gl").addClass("glHover");//Occurs when hovering over
    }, function(){  
        //Occurs when hover is done
    $('select[name="' + $(this).attr('name') + '"]').removeClass("glHover").addClass("gl");
    });
```

This is my code, basically when someone hovers over any class that is gl, it needs to find all elements with the name matching its own name, this is not working for me though and I'm pretty new to jquery so I'm not sure how to pull this off

Edited the code above, now its still not working, this is why my html looks like(Approx):

```
<table><tr>
<td class='gl' name='07/25'></td>
</td></table>
```

**Update**

```
$('td.gl').hover(function() {
$('select[name="'+ $(this).data('name') +'"]').toggleClass('gl glHover');
});
```

and

```
<td class='gl' data-name='07/18'></td>
```

Still not working

Comment: Looks like it should work. Can you post the HTML you're using this on and/or a jsFiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$(".gl").hover(function() 
    $('select[name="' + $(this).attr('name') + '"]').removeClass("gl").addClass("glHover"); 
}, function(){
    $('select[name="' + $(this).attr('name') + '"]').removeClass("glHover").addClass("gl"); 
});
```

Your element declaration was invalid as you were missing a `+` for concatenation, which in this case is for substituting the element's name attribute, and your quotes are incorrect.  I switched to single quotes since you are using double-quotes for the name attribute and the syntax was invalid.

**Update:** It seems that you want to select any element type with a name corresponding to the name of the hovered element.  Currently the usage of `select[...]` looks for a `select` element.  I would suggest you use a `class` attribute with a value for the corresponding `name` to link your elements together and then you can reference those elements with a `class` that represents that `name` attribute..

In this case try the following:

```
$(".gl").hover(function() 
    $('.' + this.name).removeClass("gl").addClass("glHover"); 
}, function(){
    $('.' + this.name).removeClass("glHover").addClass("gl"); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 $("select[name='"+$(this).attr('name')+"']")
```

should work.

Comment: This answer is incorrect.  The second `+` is missing for the name attribute inclusion.

Comment: This still isn't working for me, basically my page would look like this:
<table><tr>
<td class='gl' name='07/25'></td>
<td class='gl' name='07/25'></td>
</tr></table>

Answer (score 1):

Your code has String concatenation error, missed a `+` at end and you can get the name using `this.name`, which is faster that `$(this).attr('name')`.

```
$(".gl").hover(function() {
    $("select[name="+ this.name + "]").removeClass("gl").addClass("glHover");   
}, function(){
    $("select[name="+ this.name + "]").removeClass("glHover").addClass("gl");
});
```

**OR**

```
$(".gl").hover(function() {
    $("select[name="+ this.name + "]").removeClass("gl").addClass("glHover"); 
});
```

### `name` is not a valid attribute for `td`.

Instead of `name` use `data-name` like following:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class='gl' data-name='07/25'>07/25</td>
        <td class='gl' data-name='07/25'>07/25</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and chage jQuery code:

```
$('td.gl').hover(function() {
    $('select[name="'+ $(this).data('name') +'"]').toggleClass('gl glHover');
});
```

Comment: Well I can't use classes to find the TD's and ID's need to be unique, how else could I identify specific TD's?